When using npgsql NotificationEventHandler can I reuse the same db connection
I have a background service that runs scheduled tasks as well as looks for notification events in PostgreSQL.  Every 30 minutes or so the following function gets called.
public static async Task Main(ILogger<Worker> _logger, SiteStructure _s, int milliseconds)
{
        logger = _logger;
        s = _s;
        logger.LogInformation("Running GIS scheduled job: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
        string connectionString = s.geoConfigObj.getConnectionString();


        await using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
        await conn.OpenAsync();

        conn.Notification += (o, e) =>LoadData(_logger,conn,e.Payload);

        await using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("LISTEN data_load;", conn))
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Wait(milliseconds); // wait for events

        Console.WriteLine("Do a query.");

    }

The function will listen for notifications for 30 minutes then it will timeout on the wait event and do some other maintenance type stuff.
When it calls the LoadData function I get an error saying:
The connection is already in state 'Waiting'
Can I not reuse my connection to process the data?
